# Google map activity doesn't show anything

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I made a google map activity `(new->Google->Google Maps Activity)`. I also made google API (`google_maps_key` in xmls file). And when I call this activity only appears google map frame, not any visualization.
How to display the map? Any idea ?

Comment: Hard to guess what you forgot to do when you don't include your code. Feel free to remove the image -- we all understand what a blank screen looks like ;)

Comment: Ok, but for any cases I've posted it.

Comment: It's still not helpful. Hint: post your code!

Comment: I've just posted. But I think it doesn't matter, because I've only created the Google Maps Activity and just added the google_map_key.

Comment: Look at your logs, it likely has an error about the API key.

Comment: Ups, yes you're right. It says : "Authentication failed on the server"

Comment: I've finally solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Probably best to remove this question rather than self-answering it. It's not likely to help anyone else.

Comment: If you don't like this post/question/answer don't read. If someone has the same problem this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved this problem. 
I checked Logs and there was said "Authentication failed on the server". So, I checked `www.console.developers.google.com` and found out that the `package name` was incorrect. (This package name was automatically written) I wrote it correctly and everything works good.